# Login to website using facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-authentication, facebook-login

I am just building website for our client. It is simple page which lists some restaurations, which are practicaly scraped from facebook. My clients want to make facebook page owners to edit their week menu and restauration details on his page, but I am quite desperate, because I do not know how to authenticate them, since scraped data from facebook are without email addresses.

Is there any way how to "login as facebook page" on remote site, or do you guys have some idea how to get facebook page owners recognized?

I had also idea to let them post something on the wall (something like confirmation email), but I don't think they would be happy to post some random strings on their wall. Maybe to make them share my clients site with some specific text would be sollution, but it seems like blackmilling to me ))

I am looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Check out the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to log a user in on a remote site:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

To get an access token to be able to post to a page's wall, see the "Page Login" part of that link. Pay attention to the `manage_pages` permission you will need to ask of the page admin user.

Comment: Thanks, it is a shame that i missed it /

Comment: Yeah, it took me a couple days to figure it out the first time I tried.